# Flutter, make log from firestore data sorted by month and boolean status

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I'm writing a simple attendance application in flutter for my academic project, for any given day I have a punch in and a punch-out data which is stored to Firestore as a key "status" and a timestamp. I'm showing a log which using a listview.builder from the stream and I'm able to list the logs.
this is how I am getting currently from my stream

```
StreamBuilder<List<Punch>>(
        stream: punchBloc.outPunches,
        initialData: [],
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final punches = snapshot.data;
            return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: punches.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              final punch = punches[index];
              return LogListTile(punch: punch);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
```

[it's listed like this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Okj6.png) as you can see the status is stored and displayed one after the other consecutively.

I'm trying to make the log page with a month tab and under which I need to [see it in a single tile like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CPPd.png)

I tried so many ways but from the stream, it's still showing consecutive status, can someone guide me on how to show status n and n-1 in the same list?

appended from here to the original post.

here is my LogListTile code

```
    class LogListTile extends StatelessWidget {
  const LogListTile({
    Key key,
    @required this.punch,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Punch punch;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final textTheme = Theme.of(context).textTheme;

    return Card(
      elevation: 6,
      margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 6.0, horizontal: 16),
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
      ),
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
        padding: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10.0),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(
              color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
                  ? Colors.grey.shade900
                  : Colors.grey.shade300,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(DateFormat.yMMMd().format(punch.date)),
          //     title: Text('${punch.date.day.toString()}/${punch.date.month.toString()}/${punch.date.year.toString()}'),
          subtitle: Text(
              '${punch.status.toString()} at ${DateFormat.jm().format(punch.date)}'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You should post the LogListTile widget

Comment: added it for your reference, I need to add the punches.length and (punches.length-1) in the same list. any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

One line is generated for each value in `snapshot.data` from the `punchBloc.outPunches` stream. So you can :

- change how this stream is created
- transform the stream afterwards
- map the snapshot's data

Comment: I'm really new to the dart environment and mobile application development altogether, i really can't find many pointers as to how to accomplish this.

Comment: Well the cleanest way to do this is to edit your Punch class to hold the punch-in and punch-out data. Then, edit your bloc logic accordingly. After that, you can edit your LogListTile to show the in & out data from the Punch object.